# Approach to Problem- K-Means with distribution constraint

Tags: r, optimization, k-means

I have 4 variables *A* (continuous), *B* (continuous), *C* (categorical-binary), and *D* (categorical-multinomial) which I need to split into *K* (known) groups. However, in addition to minimizing the distance between observations based on *A* and *B*, the groups need to be as evenly distributed possible by *C* and *D*.

I am not sure how to approach this problem- is there a way that I can use a modified version of the K-means algorithm to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cluster algorithm like k-means to cluster your observations according to the variables A and B. Then you somehow also have to maximize your distance according to your variables C and D. That can be achieved by setting a  kernel, that minimizes the distance between A and B and maximizes the distance between C and D.

You can achieve this in R by using the `kkmeans` function of the `kernlab` package and specify a kernel function that is suitable for your purpose and minimizes the distance between A and B and maximizes the distance between C and D.